# Outlook Calendar notification doesn't show up on top of other windows

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook, calendar

I'm using Outlook 2007 on 64-bit Vista Business, and I've been having problems with Outlook Calendar notifications showing up behind other windows.  This leaves my only clue that I should be at a meeting that there's a blue entry on the task bar.  I haven't found a setting that relates to that.

Has anybody else had this problem?  Does anybody know how to get notification windows on top of other windows consistently?

Comment: Man, I wish I could *induce* that behaviour from Outlook. :(

Comment: @JMD:  Much as I hate windows stealing focus, I've been late for the past two Tuesday morning meetings.

Answer (score 1):

This free add-in might help force the reminder window to pop-up like you want it to:
http://blogs.kraftkennedy.com/index.php/2010/06/07/getting-outlook-meeting-reminders-in-focus-over-other-applications/

Answer (score 0):

If you want an in Outlook answer then [this post](https://superuser.com/a/462453/245358) has most of the answer. However it didn't work for me as the reminder window is not visible until the `Application_Reminder` subroutine has finished, which means `FindWindowA` can't find the reminder window.

If you've got the same issue I hacked a solution by using `SetTimer`. I'll re-post the steps in full although the top and tail is just a repeat from [the other post](https://superuser.com/a/462453/245358).

- Create a Digital certificate for later. Hit Start and type 'certificate', select 'Digital Certificate for VBA Projects'
- Enter a name for your certificate then press Done
- Open Outlook and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to start the VBA editor.
- In the tree on the left, expand 'Microsoft Office Outlook Objects' and double click on 'ThisOutlookSession'
- Paste the following code in:

> Option Explicit
>
> Private Sub Application_Quit()
>
> ' Turn off timer upon quitting VERY IMPORTANT
>       Call DeactivateTimer
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
>
> ' Call helper function in 1 second as reminder window not yet visible
>       If TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem Then ActivateTimer (1)
>
> End Sub

- Add a new module by right clicking on 'ThisOutlookSession' and then selecting Insert > Module
- In the new module (which you should have switched to) paste the following code:

> Option Explicit
>
> Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" ( _
>       ByVal lpClassName As String, _
>       ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
>
> Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
>       ByVal hwnd As Long, _
>       ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
>       ByVal X As Long, _
>       ByVal Y As Long, _
>       ByVal cx As Long, _
>       ByVal cy As Long, _
>       ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
>
> Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
>       ByVal hwnd As Long, _
>       ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
>       ByVal uElapse As Long, _
>       ByVal lpTimerfunc As Long) As Long
>
> Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
>       ByVal hwnd As Long, _
>       ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
>
> Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
>   Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
>   Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
>   Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
>
> Private TimerID As Long 'Need a timer ID to eventually turn off the timer. If the timer ID is not 0 then the timer is running
>
> Public Sub ActivateTimer(ByVal nSeconds As Long)
>
> 'The SetTimer call accepts milliseconds, so convert to seconds
>       nSeconds = nSeconds * 1000
>
> ' Check to see if timer is running before call to SetTimer
>       If TimerID <> 0 Then Call DeactivateTimer
>
> TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, nSeconds, AddressOf Reminder_Helper)
>
> If TimerID = 0 Then MsgBox "The timer failed to activate."
>
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub DeactivateTimer()
>
> Dim lSuccess As Long
>
> If TimerID <> 0 Then
>           lSuccess = KillTimer(0, TimerID)
>           If lSuccess = 0 Then
>               MsgBox "The timer failed to deactivate."
>           Else
>               TimerID = 0
>           End If
>       End If
>
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Reminder_Helper(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
>
> Dim ReminderWindowHWnd As Variant
>
> If idevent = TimerID Then
>
> On Error Resume Next
>           ReminderWindowHWnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, "1 Reminder")
>           SetWindowPos ReminderWindowHWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS
>           DeactivateTimer
>
> End If
>
> End Sub

- Sign the Macro so it will run by going to Tools > Digital Signature... and choosing the certificate you created earlier
- Close the VBA window
- Enable all macros in File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Macro Settings
- Close and re-open Outlook

I would have posted this on the bottom of [the other post](https://superuser.com/a/462453/245358) but it's locked to fresh users like me!