# Increase visibility of Windows 10 Outlook alerts

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

Outlook (Office 365) meeting alerts on Windows 10 are not clearly visible.  They don't show in foreground when triggered and the "highlighting" of the alert window in the Taskbar is not strong enough to draw your attention.  How can you improve this?

Comment: Saw this but couldn't follow these steps on the versions I'm using - https://superuser.com/questions/251963/how-to-make-outlook-calendar-reminders-stay-on-top-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, in Outlook 365, we could check the "show reminders on top of other windows" option to make meeting reminders on top. File > Options > Advanced > Reminder
[image]